# Objective-C...Why isn't the if statement working?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Calculator : NSObject

@property int numerator, denominator;

-(void) print;
-(double) convertToNum;
@end
```

---

```
#import "Calculator.h"

@implementation Calculator

@synthesize numerator, denominator;

-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}

-(double) convertToNum
{

    if (denominator != 0)
    {
        return (double) numerator / denominator;
    }
    else
    {
        return 25.68;
    }
}
@end
```

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation>
#import "Calculator.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    Calculator *myCalc = [[Calculator alloc] init];



    @autoreleasepool
    {
        //int numerator, denominator;
        //NSLog(@"Enter two numbers...");
        //scanf("%i %i", &numerator, &denominator);

        [myCalc setNumerator: 8];
        [myCalc setDenominator: 0];
        NSLog(@"The value of myFraction is: ");

        [myCalc convertToNum];
        [myCalc print];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason it always returns it as a fraction. I set it to 8 and 0 just for an example, and it returns 8/0 instead of the random number I picked to check if the else is working. Any help would be great.

Comment: This question is too basic, it doesn't belong here. You should learn objective-c programming elsewhere, then come back when you have more advanced questions.

Comment: ^ Ok I added it. 
lol I've seen way more basic questions than this on this site before, granted not for objective-c, but I'd never looked before

Comment: What do you mean "it returns 8/0 instead of the random number" ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `convertToNum` method *returns the result*, but does not change any state within the object.  Thus, the call to `print` prints what it does because the value returned from `convertToNum` is completely ignored.

Change your `print` to:

```
-(void) print
{
    NSLog(@"%i/%i = %f", numerator, denominator, [self convertToNum]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your print method, you only are printing it in that way, :

Change as suggested in the code

```
-(void) print
{
    //NSLog(@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
    NSLog(@"%f", numerator/denominator);
}
```

---

what about `[myCalc convertToNum];` this method is getting some value but you are discarding it!!!

You should use it as :

```
double value=[myCalc convertToNum];
[self print:value];
```

And then send this `value` to `print`

```
-(void) print:(double)value{
        NSLog(@"%f", value);
}
```

Comment: `[value print]`???  Surely `[self print:value]`?

Comment: @trojanfoe: oops, sorry !!! C/C++ style... i read scanf in his code and i went into dream of C++ days :D

Comment: If you say so; it doesn't look much like C or C++ and `scanf()` was C, not C++...

Comment: @trojanfoe : Actually I started my IT career as a high school teacher where 1st year C and 2nd year C++ was in syllabus. And again sorry for that silly mistake. :(

Comment: To paraphrase Danny DeVito in _Madeline_: "Great High School" :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but, I'm not actually looking to make it function better. As is probably obvious from the very basic program, I'm just learning objective-c. The book I'm using has this as one of the exercises and it seems like it should all work...but for the life of me I can't figure out why it doesn't print the other response when the denominator is 0

Comment: for 8 and 0, your answer should be 25.68

Comment: I did not get you, if you try method can method call as in my answer, you will get 25.680000 as output.